# Does Google maps for IOS have custom overlays

Tags: google-maps, ios6, google-maps-sdk-ios

As I'm going over the documentation of https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/overlays and https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays

there is a huge gap, same goes for other functionalities and abilities, I was wondering if there is a way to "wrap" the javascript abilities in order to use them in IOS applications
for example create a custom overlay or dragable marker, or even use distance, geocoding and elevation services

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `UIWebView` in your iOS app, and then use the JavaScript API in there. This gives you access to all of the features of the JavaScript API, but you would lose the iOS-specific features (like rotating/tilting the map, 3D buildings), and there are other downsides (like performance, offline use, etc).

You can use Google Maps data services like the [elevation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/) from an iOS app by making a web request to the appropriate URL, and then drawing/displaying the results within the app. It's a bit more complicated than the JavaScript API which is already integrated with the underlying maps API, but it's doable.

But yes, the major limitation of the Google Maps iOS API is its minimal support for custom overlays. The latest version includes [tile overlays](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/tiles), but if you want something more dynamic this might not be enough. There's a feature request for dynamic overlays [here](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4989), but I don't think it's on Google's priority list. Something like a draggable marker might require you to implement the dragging yourself, or it might not be possible. Annotation and overlay support is one area where Apple's MapKit still offers more flexibility than the Google Maps SDK for iOS, so you might want to take a look at that as an option (but then you can't use Google Maps data services).